# Can't use "Selection Popup Menu" Alt + Right Click (v2.76)

Tags: interface

I read this topic: "11 Useful Blender Tricks You May Not Know"

http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/11-useful-blender-tricks-you-may-not-know/

And got trouble with number **#11**: Selection Popup Menu, Hotkey: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Click</kbd>

I try to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Click</kbd> on **Object Mode** and **Edit Mode** but nothing happen, did i do wrong or miss something, i use blender 2.76, please help !!

Answer (score 1):

You have to have multiple objects in your scene. Sometimes the scene is so crowded, that some objects overlap each other, so you press the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> to choose the desired one. In my case I have the main model, the bones (metarig) and the rough proxy mesh. As you can see, when I hover the cursor over object and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> the pop up menu appears.
[image]